# How Can I add the custom Sound File in react native Urban airShip (android)

Tags: android, react-native, urbanairship.com

I am Adding Push notifications  to my app, but how can I add custom sound file in Android Platform.

first I created in Android  main folder created assets/raw/sound.mp3 file 
attached.
but this Path Added in  airshipconfig.Properties  file inside.
Is it right way or not I dont know where i can place this path please tell me the good way :

```
factory.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + "R.raw.sound.mp3"))
```

Please let me how can i add custom sound file.

I followed tutorial from [this Link](https://www.urbanairship.com/blog/mobile-app-marketing-how-to-series-adding-sound-to-alerts) to make things happen.